# .get() in ConcurrentHashMap is thread safe?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

`ConcurrentHashMap` is a thread safe collection, but what happen if `ConcurrentHashMap.get("key")` is executing and in meanwhile the map reference itself is changed. Will that produce unexpected result or it will still get the old values(this is expected).

Comment: Why do not you try and post your answer here?

Comment: an interesting question would be " how a get operation is expected to perform atomically ? " declaring volatile value for a key doesn't guarantee atomicity , if its a 64 bit object there may be two instructions to read it completely right ?

Answer (score 0):

If the map reference is being changed, either you still have the reference to the old one, and it will get fro the old map, or you have a reference to the new one, and it will get from the new one.

Setting a reference is an atomic operation, and you will never have a reference pointing to some unexisting object. The visibility of the change itself depends on whether you properly publish the new reference: it should at least be volatile if you intend any other thread to see the new reference immediately after it has been changed.